# IRC server connecting to another server

Tags: networking, irc, ircd

I'm setting up an IRC server using IRC-Hybrid,
I want my server to connect to another server, so that people on my server can connect to
channels on that other server.
I know this can be done, the GIMP IRC, is the same as the GNOME IRC

My ircd.conf contains the following:

```
connect { 
        name = "aabstractname";
        host = "128.64.2.1;
        send_password = "somepass";
        accept_password = "somepass";
        encrypted = no;
        port = 6667;
        class = "server";
        autoconn = yes;
        compressed = yes;
        fakename = "irc.sd.dom.asn.au";
};
```

So when i run:
`/etc/init.d/ircd-hybrid restart`
it should be connecting to 128.64.2.1,
but the log on 128.64.2.1, doesn't show anything

Do I need entry on the host 128.64.2.1?
I can't find any documentation for ircd.conf
I'ld really like that documentation so I can check all my settings are right.

Comment: You need an entry on both sides. Also, I'm pretty sure a server name *must* have a dot in it, otherwise the protocol breaks horribly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both sides need a connect block for the other server.**

The `connect → name` setting must be the same as the other server's `serverinfo → name`; the same for `send_password` and `accept_password`.
The reverse should be on the other server

Note: You don't need to restart the entire server for this. If you are an operator, use `/quote rehash` to reload the configuration file, then `/quote connect aabstractname` to link the servers.